# Is There A Way To Add Another Field To Custom Post Type (Not Custom Field/Meta)?

Tags: custom-post-types, customization

Maybe I'm not getting the whole concept, but is there a way to modify a Custom Post Type so that it includes other 'fields' like a 'real' db table. I don't mean a Custom Field (get_meta)... I mean inside the table that can be manipulated with rules. I want to make a post type with several -mandatory- fields.

eg.

```
Song Record:
 <Title
 <Lyrics
 <Date
 <Length
 <MP3
 :end
```

Yeah, I can do that with a bunch of custom fields, but I was wondering/hoping if this structure could all be laid out with Register_Post_Type so it could be manipulated as a single 'object'... as one can do in Drupal.

Or have I got this all wrong?

---JC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built in way to do so.  You could possibly do it via MySQL directly via [ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table.html) but you'd have to write custom code to take advantage of this yourself.  Another option is to create a new table where each set of data references a certain post.  Yet again, you'd have to manage everything yourself.

My suggestion: use a plugin like [Meta Box](https://github.com/rilwis/meta-box) or [WP Alchemy](http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/) to use the custom field system that's already there.  Either one creates a meta box of fields that'll save the custom post meta for you

Comment: Thanks. I'm one of those guys who is comfy with SQL and sometimes I find WordPress -annoying- with all the requisite calls to meta fields. Just feels messy. I think I have another way to skin this cat but it's really a separate question.

Cheers. ---JC

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean by "manipulated as a single object." Custom Fields are part of the post and as such can be manipulated anyway you like.

If you want to make a post type with mandatory fields and need an very easy way to do it, take a look at the Advanced Custom Fields plugin. You can set conditions on when and where fields appear and there are a bunch of different field types. Another plus is the great support that the developer offers.

You can find it here http://advancedcustomfields.com